# Is it possible to see which comment I flagged where I get a 'declined' response in my flagging history?

Tags: feature-request, flags, comments, declined-flags

I recently reported a comment [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468816/how-to-read-and-edit-csv-file-using-java-swing) and it was declined, but I do not recall which one I reported. I imagine it was this one, since it doesn't sound very constructive to me:

> ok if u dont want to help then its ok.So please dont take interest @ Andrew Thompson – user3599030 May 5 '14 at 9:28

It seems to me that it would be helpful to have the flag history screen show which comment was flagged - in this case there are five comments and the page does not make it clear which one I flagged (unless there is a clever alt-text I am missing!).

The only information available about this flag is:

> not constructive – halfer 2 days ago   declined

This change would be helpful for readers who feel that a moderator decision was wrong, and wish to discuss it on Meta (I am not fussed about it - most of my flags are accepted and I generally won't query the few that are not).

I would guess that would be no need to connect *accepted* flags to the comments they pertain to, since readers are unlikely to want to see a comment they have objected to in the first place.

Comment: Or maybe you accidentally flagged the wrong comment.... but we'll never know without moderator intervention.  So we're back to the same problem.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, yes, good point - that might explain the unexpected mod response.

Comment: Or maybe the mod fat-fingered and declined the flag but deleted the comment. I agree, it would be nice to be able to see this.

Comment: Jut out of curiosity if you try to flag it again does the flag box come up?

Comment: @Nathan: the comment was flaggable after it had been declined, so no clues there. However it has now been deleted, so the evidence of someone's fat-fingering is fast disappearing. It's a whitewash! `:-)`

Comment: Yes, that was the comment you flagged the first time, too.

Comment: Also for the purpose of learning what you should and should not flag being able to see which flags are accepted and which aren't is helpful.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question when I found yours. I hope this feature request is implemented.